Is relinquishing US citizenship without formal renunciation possible?
I read here:

Relinquishment can happen without the individual's explicit intention to abandon their citizenship.

However, Afroyim v. Rusk says this:

Under the Citizenship Clause of the Fourteenth Amendment, a U.S. citizen cannot lose his or her citizenship unless he or she willingly surrenders it.

How do these two claims reconcile? Under what legal authority can a relinquishment happen without the individual's explicit intention to abandon their citizenship?

"How do these two claims reconcile?" The most likely explanation I can think of is that the first claim is the result of AI hallucination.  I'm tempted to call the lawyer and ask for a consultation on those grounds.

You can "willingly surrender" without "explicit intention". Current policy makes that unlikely in this case, but it's a common principle of common law, criminal and civil. cf murder and manslaughter: cf contracts.


Is relinquishing US citizenship without formal renunciation possible?

Yes, it is possible to lose US citizenship through certain actions other than a formal renunciation in front of a consular officer, but those actions have to be performed with the intention of relinquishing US citizenship.

I read here:
Relinquishment can happen without the individual's explicit intention to abandon their citizenship.

Under current law, it is not possible to lose US citizenship (that was obtained properly), under any circumstances, without the individual's intention to relinquish their citizenship. However, the quoted sentence says, "explicit intention", not just "intention", so I guess it is not technically incorrect, since intention doesn't have to be "explicit". The intention must be proven by "a preponderance of the evidence".
The only current law that provides for loss of US citizenship (that was obtained properly) is INA 349 (8 USC 1481). This only allows loss of US nationality by performing certain acts with the intention of relinquishing US nationality:

(a) A person who is a national of the United States whether by birth
or naturalization, shall lose his nationality by voluntarily
performing any of the following acts with the intention of
relinquishing United States nationality-

Subsection (b) provides that the burden of proof for a claim for loss of citizenship is on the party claiming the loss, to prove it "by a preponderance of the evidence":

(b) Whenever the loss of United States nationality is put in issue in
any action or proceeding commenced on or after September 26, 1961
under, or by virtue of, the provisions of this chapter or any other
Act, the burden shall be upon the person or party claiming that such
loss occurred, to establish such claim by a preponderance of the
evidence.

In Vance v. Terrazas (1980), the US Supreme Court confirmed that the intention must be proven by a preponderance of the evidence:


[...] While the statute provides that any of the statutory expatriating acts, if proved, is presumed to have been committed
voluntarily, it does not also direct a presumption that the act has
been performed with the intent to relinquish United States
citizenship, which matter remains the burden of the party claiming
expatriation to prove by a preponderance of the evidence.


In subsequent proceedings, Terrazas was found to have lost US citizenship due to his having sworn an oath to Mexico which said he was "renouncing US citizenship", and the courts found that, based on the record, there was a preponderance of evidence that he intended to relinquish US citizenship, despite his denying such intention to the court. I am not sure whether you can say there was "explicit intention" in his case.
Subsequent to the Terrazas ruling, the Department of State adopted an administrative presumption (see 22 CFR 50.40(a)) that the person does not intend to relinquish citizenship for three of the potentially expatriating acts (naturalizing in a foreign country, taking a routine oath of allegiance, and taking a non-policy level position in a foreign government). While this administrative presumption stands, these three potentially expatriating acts will not cause loss of US citizenship without an affirmative assertion of intention to relinquish citizenship from the person to a consular officer. (This would have helped Terrazas if it had existed at the time of his oath.)
However, in the other potentially expatriating acts (e.g. serving in foreign armed forces as an officer or armed forces in hostilities with the US, serving in policy level position in a foreign government, committing an act of treason or bearing arms against the US), the presumption doesn't apply, and it is still the case that loss of US citizenship can be determined by a preponderance of evidence that the person intended to relinquish citizenship, even without the person's affirmative assertion of that intention.

I know of quite a few US citizens serving as officers in foreign militaries (Israel, for example), and have never heard of any one of them having their US citizenship questioned. In fact, Afroyim precedent is also about a US/Israeli dual citizen. That said, the link I posted talks about ties, maintaining passport, etc. Not swearing an oath to a foreign country at all. I am aware of an ISIS fighter who was stripped of US citizenship under this section, so it does seem to have been used after Afroyim and Terrazas

It's different for naturalized citizens.
From your first link:

The United States Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS)
requires naturalized citizens to demonstrate their intent to maintain
a connection to the country. Extended periods of living overseas might
raise questions about whether the individual genuinely intends to
remain a US citizen.
The general rule is that a naturalized citizen who voluntarily resides
outside the US for an uninterrupted period of more than one year may
be presumed to have abandoned their US citizenship.

Irregularities in the naturalization process can also cause citizenship to be revoked, primarily misrepresentations during application.
There is no equivalent method for losing citizenship for natural born citizens.  Maybe participation in a "terrorist" organization, but those are very edge cases.

I'm not asking about revocation due to misrepresentation or fraud and such, I'm asking about relinquishing. You're quoting from the link I provided whereas I was asking for the legal authority on which it is based.

The second quoted paragraph describes the state of the law in the early 20th century.  It is absolutely 100% incorrect from the 1960s onward, if not the 1950s or earlier.  It is also rather closer to being accurate if you replace the word "citizen" with the phrase "permanent resident."  I would suspect an AI hallucination.  Try calling the firm and asking to talk to a lawyer because you're concerned about a finding of abandoned citizenship after having lived abroad for 5 years, and see what happens.

@littleadv asked how the claims reconcile: Tiger Guy pointed out one way in which the claims are reconciled. If littleadv did not mean to ask how the claims could be reconciled,  littleadv should edit the OP to remove that question.

@david  No, this answer doesn't help reconcile the claims. Fraudulently obtained citizenship is not relinquished, it's revoked.

@littleadv You confuse fraud with demonstration of intent? Legally, those are not the same thing.

@david yes, exactly. So how is this answer relevant to my question?

@littleadv asked how the claims reconcile: Tiger Guy pointed out one way in which the claims are reconciled: by demonstration of intent. littleadv confused that with fraud. If littleadv did not mean to ask how the claims could be reconciled, littleadv should edit the OP to remove that question

@david didn't mean to offend you, I know English is a hard language and you probably don't understand the difference between relinquishment and revocation. The question was about the former, and the answer discusses the latter. These are not the same things. It's easy to get confused, I'm sure, but it's OK. No harm done.
